# Java - Search Oracle DB for a row with spaces (ORA-00920)

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to execute a `select` query from Java, the tricky part is that both the condition and the `column` have a String with `spaces` :

```
String query = "select  rule_name "+ 
    " from rules " +
    " where  rule_name = " m_rule; //rule_name = str tf //m_rule = str tf
```

So the query output :

```
select rule_name
from rules
where rule_name = str tf
```

The error code - `ORA-00920` - I belive it is because of the spaces.
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This is one of many cases for using prepared statements with parameters. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html.

Comment: That will get ORA-00933 "command not properly ended" with the `str tf` value you've shown?

Comment: @AlexPoole for now the error is the ORA-00920. why ORA-00933?

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are facing basically means :

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

This is the blank that is causing the issue. Your Java code should enclose the conditional parameter in quotes:

```
String query = "select  rule_name "+ 
    " from rules " +
    " where  rule_name = '" + m_rule + "'";
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: The string value from `m_rule`  be enclosed by single quotes, not double quotes. Prepared statement with bind parameters would be better anyway of course.

Comment: Trying and posting the answer.